Identify this post apocalyptic movie with rival cannibal car gangs

Released between 1990 and 2010
There are two rival gangs of cannibals (or maybe only one of them is) driving around in modified cars in a post apocalyptic world
They've got tattoos and weird piercings
Plot has something to do with saving someone from a cannibal gang
There is a scene in which the cannibals have tied up the victim and are going to kill/cook him
Not a famous movie


Doomsday?  https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=mJMjiCxHLdg

This sounds like the 2008 English-language science fiction film, Doomsday, written and directed by Neil Marshall. He drew inspiration from various movies  (Mad Max, Escape from New York and 28 Days Later)


Sinopsis (WIKIPEDIA):

In 2008, a killer virus, known as the "The Reaper Virus", has infected
  the country of Scotland. Unable to contain the outbreak or cure the
  infected, The UK government built a massive 60-foot wall that isolated
  Scotland from the rest of Britain. The quarantine was deemed a
  success; however, the extreme method employed by the government
  destroyed diplomatic and economic relations between the UK and the
  rest of the world. This led to massive unemployment, civil unrest and
  extreme economic turmoil, causing the UK to collapse into a dystopia.
In 2035, 27 years after the quarantine, during a raid, police discover
  several people infected with Reaper Virus. The Prime Minister John
  Hatcher shares with domestic security chief Captain Nelson satellite
  footage of survivors in Scotland. Believing a cure may exist, Hatcher
  orders Nelson to send a team into Scotland to find medical researcher
  Dr. Kane, who was working on a cure when Scotland was quarantined.
  Nelson chooses Major Eden Sinclair to lead the team.
Sinclair's team crosses the wall and goes to Glasgow, Dr. Kane's last
  known location. In Glasgow, while searching the local hospital for
  survivors, Sinclair and her team are ambushed by a group of marauders.
  Sgt. Norton and Dr. Stirling manage to escape, while the team suffers
  heavy casualties. Sinclair and Dr. Talbot are captured by what turns
  out to be a huge gang of brutal cannibals. Sinclair is
  interrogated by the gang's leader, Sol, who plans to use her as
  leverage to cross the wall and invade England. It's the only way to
  change the UK back to its formal glory. He then leaves for the
  sacrificial ceremony to join the rest of the gang, who grill Dr.
  Talbot and eat him. With the help of Cally, another prisoner,
  Sinclair escapes and kills Viper, Sol's dedicated partner. After
  meeting with Norton and Stirling, they escape on a train. Cally
  reveals that she and Sol are Kane's children. Unsatisfied with Kane's
  rule, Sol left to create his own army.
Meanwhile, Hatcher plans secretly to isolate the central London area
  because of the infection. However, an infected man breaks into his
  office and tries to kill him. Nelson shoots and kills the man, but his
  blood splatters on Hatcher. Michael Canaris, Hatcher's right-hand man,
  quarantines him and takes his place as de facto Prime Minister.
  Hatcher later commits suicide.
After leaving the train, Sinclair's group are arrested by soldiers
  armed with archaic weapons and armor. They are taken to a medieval
  castle and imprisoned. Their leader, Marcus Kane, tells Sinclair the
  truth: there is no cure, only people with a natural immunity.
  Originally a medical researcher, he was devastated when his family was
  left behind during the quarantine. After losing his wife, Kane became
  a twisted, sadistic leader. He sentences Sinclair and her group to
  death, pitting Sinclair against Telamon, his executioner, in a small
  fighting ground to entertain his followers. Sinclair subdues and kills
  Telamon. During the duel, the rest of the group escapes, retrieves
  their equipment and rescue Sinclair.
Sinclair, Norton, Stirling and Cally escape to a fallout shelter
  entrance on horseback. They locate an underground facility in the
  forest and find an intact 2007 Bentley Continental GT, which they fuel
  up. Kane's medieval knights arrive and kill Norton. Sinclair and the
  others drive the Bentley back to the quarantine wall. On the way, they
  are intercepted by Sol's gang, who seeks to avenge Viper's death.
  After a high-speed chase, Sol and many of his men are killed and
  Sinclair's group escape.
The car is tracked down by a government gunship. Canaris arrives and
  reveals he will let the virus continue as a form of population control
  and profit. Cally's blood is to be used as a vaccine for the virus.
  Cally and Stirling board the gunship, while Sinclair chooses to stay
  behind. Nelson flies into the quarantine zone to speak with Sinclair
  and she gives him a recording of the conversation, the evidence to
  bring down Canaris. The recording is later broadcast to the rest of
  the country. Sinclair retrieves Sol's head and returns to his gang.
  Looking at the head, the marauders cheer, accepting Sinclair as their
  new leader.











IMDB
Trailer
